# Can you use mysql to change database value, if it is past a date?

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

Let's say I have two column. DATE   and    STATUS.

When a new row comes in, STATUS has a default that gets set. Status has four values:

```
Not Answered, 
Just Asked (Default), 
Answered, 
Closed
```

Let's say after 2 days, I would like it to automatically change to Not Answered, can I use mysql to do this? Or do I have to use some scripting language like PHP and run it daily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be best accomplished with a cron script that you run every night.

```
UPDATE `my_table` SET status = 'Not answered' WHERE date = ADDDATE( now(), -2 );
```

You might need to check the date format 1st though.

Comment: I am not familiar with the term cron script, can you explain a little? Sorry I'm semi-new at this!

Comment: A cronscript is a php file, that you run from CLI via sheduled task.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much! That would work just fine for me! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use an 'after insert' trigger for the next insert to update existing values. But if you can't rely on new values consistently being entered then a cron job is your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

use a cron script that you run every time you need, for example for a mysql you can use:

```
mysql -h hostname -u username -ppassword -e "query to run"
```